# YouCompleteMe cannot find module

Tags: microsoft-windows, plugin-you-complete-me, vimscript-python

I am trying to get YCM working on Windows 10.

- Vim version: `8.1 64-bit GUI`
- Since I'm using the regular gvim installer for Windows I have python support
- Compiler flags as follows:

```
Compilation: cl -c /W3 /nologo  -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_PATHDEF -DWIN32  -DFEAT_CSCOPE -DFEAT_TERMINAL -DFEAT_SOUND  -DFEAT_JOB_CHANNEL      -DWINVER=0x0501 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 /MP -DHAVE_STDINT_H /Ox /GL -DNDEBUG  /Zl /MT -DFEAT_MBYTE_IME -DDYNAMIC_IME -DDYNAMIC_ICONV -DDYNAMIC_GETTEXT -DFEAT_TCL -DDYNAMIC_TCL -DDYNAMIC_TCL_DLL=\"tcl86t.dll\" -DDYNAMIC_TCL_VER=\"8.6\" -DFEAT_LUA -DDYNAMIC_LUA -DDYNAMIC_LUA_DLL=\"lua53.dll\" -DFEAT_PYTHON -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON_DLL=\"python27.dll\" -DFEAT_PYTHON3 -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3 -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3_DLL=\"python37.dll\" -DFEAT_MZSCHEME -I "C:\Program Files\Racket\include" -DMZ_PRECISE_GC -DDYNAMIC_MZSCHEME -DDYNAMIC_MZSCH_DLL=\"libracket3m_a36fs8.dll\" -DDYNAMIC_MZGC_DLL=\"libracket3m_a36fs8.dll\" -DFEAT_PERL -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DDYNAMIC_PERL -DDYNAMIC_PERL_DLL=\"perl528.dll\" -DFEAT_RUBY -DDYNAMIC_RUBY -DDYNAMIC_RUBY_VER=24 -DDYNAMIC_RUBY_DLL=\"x64-msvcrt-ruby240.dll\" -DFEAT_HUGE /Fd.\ObjCULYHTRZAMD64/ /Zi
Linking: link  /nologo /opt:ref /LTCG:STATUS oldnames.lib kernel32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib gdi32.lib  comdlg32.lib ole32.lib netapi32.lib uuid.lib /machine:AMD64   libcmt.lib  user32.lib  /nodefaultlib:lua53.lib  /STACK:8388608
/nodefaultlib:python27.lib /nodefaultlib:python37.lib   "C:\Tcl\lib\tclstub86.lib" winmm.lib WSock32.lib /PDB:vim.pdb -debug
```

- Python3.7 installed to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64`
- Python37.dll is present in the same folder as python.exe
- `:echo has('python3')` returns 1
- YCM was installed as follows:

```
python install.py --clang-completer --ts-completer --cs-completer
```

- No error during YCM installation
- YCM Logs shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\<user>\.vim\bundle\YouCompleteMe\third_party\ycmd\ycmd\utils.py", line 639, in ImportAndCheckCore
   ycm_core = ImportCore()
 File "C:\Users\<user>\.vim\bundle\YouCompleteMe\third_party\ycmd\ycmd\utils.py", line 630, in ImportCore
   import ycm_core as ycm_core
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You might have more luck asking on [ycm's issue tracker](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/issues), but I hope one of our community experts can answer your question

Comment: Have you found any solution yet ?

Comment: @AP2008 answers are not for comments on the question. If you don’t have the rep to comment, you may earn it through other use of the site. Welcome to [vi.se]!